# Count how often duplicates occur

Tags: elasticsearch, distinct, aggregation

In Elasticsearch, I am trying to *count* the number of *distinct* field values in the dataset where the field value:

- Appears exactly once.
- Appears twice or more.

In a sense, I am trying to count how often duplicates occur. How can I do this?

#### Example

Let's say I have the following Elasticsearch documents:

```
{ "myfield": "bob" }
{ "myfield": "bob" }
{ "myfield": "alice" }
{ "myfield": "eve" }
{ "myfield": "mallory" }
```

Since "alice", "eve" and "mallory" appear once, and "bob" appears twice, I would expect:

```
number_of_values_that_appear_once: 3
number_of_values_that_appear_twice_or_more: 1
```

I can get part of the way with a [terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and looking at the `doc_count` of each bucket. The output of a terms aggregation on `myfield` would look something like:

```
"buckets": [
  {
    "key": "bob",
    "doc_count": 3
  },
  {
    "key": "alice",
    "doc_count": 1
  },
  ...
]
```

From this output, I could just sum the number of buckets where `doc_count == 1` for example. But this does not scale because I often have many thousands of distinct values so the bucket list would be enormous.

Comment: have you found  the solution for this?

Comment: @Kostanos Unfortunately not, and I'm also not really working with Elasticsearch at the moment, so I also don't think there's a solution in sight. If I recall correctly, we ended up with the solution outlined above, which works OK up to a few thousand buckets, but getting beyond hundred thousand, it is not scalable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can count duplicates via a scripted_metric based solution. A similar solution is explained in article "[Accurate Distinct Count and Values from Elasticsearch](https://pratik-patil.medium.com/accurate-distinct-count-and-values-from-elasticsearch-dadce51ad4a7)". All you need to do is modify the solution query to count each occurrence of unique value instead of counting the unique values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregations are affected by your query, so, if you want to find duplications just run the query below:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "YOUR_AGGREGATION_NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myfield"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ps1: The `size` key just omits the results/hits (except the total).

ps2: The `query` key is matching all the documents in the index.

Comment: That query is exactly what I have already tried and it won't scale since I have so many distinct values. At the end of my question, I wrote: "But this does not scale because I often have many thousands of distinct values so the bucket list would be enormous."